# sc createservice success even if password is wrong

Tags: powershell

I am using the powershell command to config the credentials for a service.

If user name is in-correct then I am getting proper error message, says "The account name is invalid or does not exist or the password is invalid for the account name specified."

But if user name is correct and password is wrong then it creates the service but did not start.

My question is, if password is invalid then services should not be created. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to achieve it?

Comment: Once service is registered then it automatically tries to start that service and after several tries, the account gets locked. Do you know, how can we verify inside batch file that entered credentials are not correct?

Comment: Hi @Bill_Stewart, While trying to add assembly using batch file I am getting error. Running this statement FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%p IN (`powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"`) DO SET AddType=%%p "Cannot find type [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]: verify that the assembly"